# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::get_compiled_select()?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I've the following sql active record query which is giving this error. I have inner select queries so that why I tried to use this method that i found on google but it's giving error that get_complied_select is not defined. How to solve this error or is there any other better way to write following queries? Thanks!

```
        $this->db->select('id_dem');
    $this->db->from('dem_demos');
    $this->db->where('id_dem IN (".implode("," ,$id_v).") OR maindemo_dem IN (".implode(",",$id_v).")');
    $innermost_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(demo_vis) as tot_visits');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N" AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN 
    ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e."');
    $first_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(demo_vis) as tot_visits');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N"
                  AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e." AND 
                  invited_vis = 0');
    $second_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(demo_vis) as tot_visits');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N"
                  AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e." AND 
                  invited_vis > 0');
    $third_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(conversion_vis)');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N"
                  AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e." AND 
                  invited_vis = 0 AND conversion_vis = 1');
    $fourth_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(buy_vis)');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N"
                  AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e." AND 
                  buy_vis = 1');
    $fifth_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $this->db->select('COUNT(distinct session_vis) as unique_visits');
    $this->db->from('sta_views');
    $this->db->where('countvisit_wis != "N"
                  AND demo_vis IN $innermost_query AND date_vis BETWEEN ".$date_s." AND ".$date_e."');
    $sixth_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $query  = $this->db->select('$first_query as total_views, $second_query as website_views, $third_query as demosent_views,
    $fourth_query as website_conversions, $fifth_query as buy_now_clicks, $$sixth_query as unique_views');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row_array();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Set database config file. `$active_record = TRUE;` and try

Comment: post your error message as well

Comment: Change this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` in `auotoload.php`,

Comment: I solved this issue by adding get_compiled_select() function in system/database/DB_driver.php file. It was not there previously that's why it was giving error of undefined.

Comment: If you are going to add SQL to your select lines you need to add a FALSE parameter like this: `$this->db->select("count(..)....", FALSE)` ..also I saw this: `$$sixth_query`, is that a typo?

Comment: #CodeGodie, yes it was an typo error.